# Java Outprinting Large File Line By Line

Tags: java, string, out

Every time I do something like

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        br.close();
```

It won't outprint line by line. Instead it will lag for 2-3 seconds then show it all at once. I've tried putting sleep methods etc. How can I make it so it takes its time and goes through each one rather than just lagging and spitting it all out at once?

Comment: what are the contents of your file ? give some sample output

Comment: Are you sure the file has newlines? In an editor make the window bigger and the lines should not reformat. In Linux or OS X run 'cat <file> | od -c' to see the \r\n (windows newlines) or \n (*nix newlines)

Comment: Oh, and a combination of the different newlines will cause a problem like you describe also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try flushing the output.

```
System.out.flush();
```

After each System.out.println

Comment: What if it wasn't to outprint it? What if I was just running voids for each line

Comment: What do you mean by "running voids" ? Is the file an empty file with a bunch of new lines?

Comment: For each line in the file I send it to a website to authorize. It outprints each authorization. Rather than outprinting then pausing than outprinting. It lags 2-3 seconds then outprints every single thing

Comment: Then you need to change your question because you are obviously not doing System.out.println.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because your file doesn't have carriage return characters at the end of each line. So, it's considering the entire file as one line.

Comment: It's not though, Because I'm running voids for each line

Comment: @Master What do you mean?

Comment: @haley Let's say I have a void that does other things with each line. Like for each line a website validates the line. I have it doing that right now, but it ends up lagging and doing it all at once. Isn't their a way it does it by line then waits and does it by line so it shows up like this on the display . . . . Rather than *pause* .....

Comment: How big is the file? I'm unable to replicate this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the lines to an array list. See if the arraylist contains each line. Then try iterating the array list to the website chunk by chunk.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(line); 
        }
        br.close();

       for(String one_line: list){
        //send lines to website: 
        //sendLine(one_line);
        }
```